# How can I method chain JQuery JayQ functions in Clojurescript?

Tags: clojurescript

In JQuery I can do something like:

```
$("#p1").css("color","red").slideUp(2000).slideDown(2000);
```

:and it runs them in order, but when I try the following in Clojurescript JayQ:

```
(-> $("#p1")
  (css "color" "red")
  (slideUp 2000)
  (slideDown 2000)
)
```

: then the methods do not run one after the other. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JayQ syntax is slightly different. This should be more accurate:

```
(-> ($ "#p1")
    (css {:color "red"})
    (slide-up 2000)
    (slide-down 2000))
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed the extra braces!

Comment: I think there is more syntactic differences. :)

Answer (score 9):

I can't speak to jayq, but if you are trying to interop directly with jQuery you need to use the dot syntax to interop:

```
(-> (js/$ "#p1")
    (.css "color" "red")
    (.slideUp 2000)
    (.slideDown 2000))
```

Comment: What about the  (css {:color "red"}), is it needed?

Comment: If you pass a ClojureScript hashmap to jQuery, it will explode with confusion. You can create a plain JavaScript object in ClojureScript pretty easily though: `(js-obj)` and then use `aset` and `aget` to set and get properties (be sure to use strings instead of keywords for the keys).